# How to handle a day light saving issue properly in ASP.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have gone through many answers and articles but I havent got the better solution.
I have to set a reminder for daily, weekly or monthly from different regions.
Even if I convert the time into UTC also there will be issues when the region is prone to Daylight saving.

Comment: *"Even if I convert the time into UTC also there will be issues when the region is prone to Daylight saving"* That's not how UTC works...

Comment: Can you be more specific if you don't mind?

Comment: UTC doesn't have daylight saving time, store all your times in UTC and you won't have to do any conversions.

Comment: Well the *question* isn't specific. In particular "there will be issues" is far too vague. Your answer contains a `dateTimeStamp` with no explanation, and no obvious expectation of whether that's a daily, weekly, monthly value etc.

Comment: @DavidG: Except that doesn't work for repeated events. If you have a repeated event that occurs every Monday at 4pm in Los Angeles, then converting 4pm to UTC once doesn't help.

Comment: Basically, "do everything in UTC" is advice which is often given and only appropriate for certain situations.

Comment: @JonSkeet That's a fair point. Does Noda Time have a feature to help in this situation? :)

Comment: @DavidG: Well it makes *everything* easier, of course :) This is feasible with `DateTime`, but the code won't be as clear.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by using this code.
We will get the TimeZoneInfo from TimezoneId

```
var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(TimezoneId);
```

convert the DateTime into a timestamp

```
   private DateTime ComputeNextUtcTimeToRun(long dateTimeStamp, TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo)
        {
            try
            {
                // Get the current time in the target time zone
                DateTime now = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, timeZoneInfo);

                // Compute the next local time
                DateTime scheduledLocalTime = (new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)).AddMilliseconds(dateTimeStamp).ToLocalTime();

                if (scheduledLocalTime < now)
                {
                    scheduledLocalTime = scheduledLocalTime.AddDays(1);
                }
                // If it's invalid, advance.  The clocks shifted forward!
                if (timeZoneInfo.IsInvalidTime(scheduledLocalTime))
                {
                    return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(scheduledLocalTime.AddHours(1), timeZoneInfo);
                }
                // If it's ambiguous, pick the first instance
                if (timeZoneInfo.IsAmbiguousTime(scheduledLocalTime))
                {
                    TimeSpan offset = timeZoneInfo.GetAmbiguousTimeOffsets(scheduledLocalTime).Max();
                    DateTimeOffset dto = new DateTimeOffset(scheduledLocalTime, offset);
                    return dto.UtcDateTime;
                }
                return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime.SpecifyKind(scheduledLocalTime, DateTimeKind.Unspecified), timeZoneInfo);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

[Please refer this link for more information](https://codeofmatt.com/2015/03/06/common-daylight-saving-time-mistakes-for-net-developers/)

please correct me if it can be made better.

Comment: @CalC No it shouldn't, it's a self answer, not a problem here. The quality of the answer... a different question.

Comment: Thanks @DavidG. SO seems nuts sometimes. Is there a guide/meta on this?

Comment: @CalC see [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) in the help section.